# checking for an array within a 2D array using IntStream

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java-stream

I'm looking to check if a set of coordinates (`coor`) exists within an array of coordinates (`coorArray`). I've seen in other posts how to concatenate the 2D array so that it can be searched for in an `IntStream` for a lone `int` but I'm not sure how to translate that towards my problem. Thank you for the help!

example arrays:

```
int[][] coorArray = {{1,2},{2,2},{3,0}};
int[] coor = {1,2};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yoy can use [`stream().anyMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) to perform this check:

```
int[][] coorArray = {{1,2},{2,2},{3,0}};
int[] coor = {1,2};
boolean exist = Arrays.stream(coorArray).anyMatch(e -> Arrays.equals(e, coor));
System.out.println("exist = " + exist);
```

Outputs:

> `exist = true`

---

Otherwise, when coordinates is not exists in input array:

```
int[][] coorArray = {{4,2},{2,2},{3,0}};
int[] coor = {1,2};
boolean exist = Arrays.stream(coorArray).anyMatch(e -> Arrays.equals(e, coor));
System.out.println("exist = " + exist);
```

Outputs:

> `exist = false`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example without lambda expressions if you like ;). Consisting of a simple for each and the check per coordinate.

```
public static boolean exists(int[][] coords, int[] coord){
    for(int[] c : coords){
        if(c[0] == coord[0] && c[1] == coord[1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm not sure if there is something else available in the API but that should serve the requirement.

Comment: author is asking about stream operations but it is always correct too (+)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ you are right, I think I actually misunderstood the question because it isn't showing the stream but rather the two array sorry. But I'm still not 100% sure what the OP wants.

Comment: These both appear to be good solutions I'll be trying them both out. Thank you! @StrangerintheQ